# HP MSS EX485 no drives lights, no physical drive found

Tags: troubleshooting, windows-server-2003, hp-mediasmart

My HP EX485 stopped working about a week ago. It has one factory Seagate 750GB and 2 WD 1.0 TB drives with the factory processor.

I removed all but the factory installed Seagate 750gb, Barracuda 7200.11. Unit Powers Up with the following light status:

- ON light - steady blue
- NETWORK - steady blue
- HEALTH - blinking blue
- HARD DRIVE bar - no light

Should I be getting some kind of light activity at the HD Light Bar? What am I missing?

I have a VOV Technology cable board with mouse, keyboard, and monitor attached. I pulled all of my drives out started the server it goes into recovery mode I can watch it work. After it boots I slide the main factory drive and run the HPMSS Recovery the server is found I have tried the server recovery on the factory Seagate 750 and Factory Reset on a new WD 1.0 TB drive.  With the same results FAILURE, no physical disk on the server.

What can I try next?  I'm getting this sinking feeling in my stomach.

Comment: When that happened to me it turned out to be a bad drive, but seeing that it still happens to you with a NEW drive, it may be a failure of the SATA controller.